# Using Schedule to run jobs at certain times

Tags: python, schedule

I am trying to schedule a few jobs and thanks to stackoverflow I was able to find Schedule (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule).

Unfortunately this isn't documented very well. I have a list of jobs I am trying to run, each with a certain time in a single day that it is supposed to be run.

```
for i in jobArray:
    # compareTimes returns a boolean that indicates if it's time to run it, assume it works.
    if compareTimes(i.time):
        # I want to schedule this job for a specific time, i.time
        schedule.every().day.do(job)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)
```

This is what I came up with. Obviously this is wrong (it gets stuck in the while loop). There is no documentation for .run_pending() so I don't know how to fix it to get it to work. Please assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is what I came up with. Obviously this is wrong (it gets stuck in
>   the while loop). There is no documentation for .run_pending() so I
>   don't know how to fix it to get it to work. Please assist.

That appears to be the correct behaviour. The scheduler is checking for pending jobs every 60 seconds, and (I assume) is running them as they come in. It is supposed to run forever, because are you scheduling jobs perpetually with `schedule.every().day.do(job)`. Your problem is that you need to run this program in the background.

If you are interested in something that is suitable for a production environment, I suggest taking a look at either [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (which my very well be overkill) or [Python RQ](http://python-rq.org/). These are well documented, distributed, and can run in the background out of the box.

Comment: I put a print statement inside the if branch. It never gets run once the while loop starts.

Comment: @ZtoYi what is compareTimes doing with i.time? what is i.time? Check those.

Comment: compareTimes works. I have checked it thoroughly. If I run this program at the time it is supposed to be run the if loop will be entered.

Comment: @ZtoYi What is meant by 'the time it's supposed to be run?' The purpose of the scheduling queue is to have the 'the time it's supposed to be run' handled for you.

Comment: In my use case I am looking at different time zones. Therefore, as opposing to hard coding a time for a job to run, I have the if statement to check if it is indeed time for it to run.

Comment: @ZtoYi _I put a print statement inside the if branch_, yes this will only be executed once - when scheduling the jobs. then only the `job` function will run, once every day as per your example. put the print statement in `job` and you will see it run at the scheduled intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution I think works as it should: The main thread is blocked by looping. The work you registered with  `schedule.every().day.do(job)` will be called every day. Remind that the jobs are executed serially! 
I think in the order as you have registered them.

For a solution without blocking the main thread see this [Code](https://github.com/mrhwick/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L63) (run_continuously method).

For some examples see [here](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/FAQ.rst).

Comment: What does it mean that jobs are executed serially? Suppose I have a job that's schedule to run at 3:00, another scheduled at 2:00 (respectively). The 2:00 job will always run before the 3:00 job, even if it is ordered after, right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Serially means that the next job will be executed after the one before has finished its work. So the 2pm job starts first. The 3pm job will start only at its time if the 2pm job is finished! If 2pm is not finished the 3pm job will be delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this line :

```
schedule.every().day.do(job)
```

You didn't specify the time you need to run the script at in the day , and the correct syntax is :

```
schedule.every().day.at("00.00").do(job)
```

now by adding

```
.at('xx:xx')
```

script can work correctly

**Note** : if the time you specify for example is : `'4:13'` then it will return an error and the correct format is `'04:13'` means it must be `'xx:xx'`

I tried the code and it worked correctly so hope this solves your problem.